# jQuery Selectable list as calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I would like to create a simply calendar which is represented by 7 columns (as days) and a few rows (for example 6 rows - every row for 4 hours).

the result should be like:

```
        monday        tuesday        wednesday    ...
0-4     listItem      listItem       listItem
4-8     listItem      listItem       listItem
8-12    listItem      listItem       listItem
12-16   listItem      listItem       listItem
...
```

then the user should be able to select a few `listItem`- including 'across days' (by click on the first element and drag the cursor on the next or previous).

I use a `selectable` from jqueryUi - https://jqueryui.com/selectable/#default
but it works only for list in one column.

I tried to modify the code and added `column-count: 2;` as `ol` css attribute:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <style>
  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; border: 2px solid black}
  ol{
    column-count: 2;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>


</body>
</html>
```

but there is a problem because the select order is wrong:
[image]

There is also a `grid selectable` list elements - https://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid but the order is not correct for my case (the order is by rows, not by columns).

How is it possible to create multiple columns from one `ol` list and use `selectable jqueryUi` on this elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like `float: left;` versus `column-count: 2;`. Either way, I would advise setting a proper width and height for the `ol`. This will make it easier for selectable to work.

**Example 1**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").selectable();
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 240px;
}

#selectable li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

If you need more row and column control, I would switch to a `table` element. Or make multiple columns from multiple Lists.

**Example 2**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".week-days").selectable({
    filter: ".day-list > td"
  });
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.day-list .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
  border-color: #999;
}

.day-list .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.day-list td {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.2em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  height: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="week-days">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="day-list">
        <th>0 - 4</th>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>Item 7</td>
        <td>Item 13</td>
        <td>Item 19</td>
        <td>Item 25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="day-list">
        <th>4 - 8</th>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>Item 8</td>
        <td>Item 14</td>
        <td>Item 20</td>
        <td>Item 26</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="day-list">
        <th>8 - 12</th>
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>Item 9</td>
        <td>Item 15</td>
        <td>Item 21</td>
        <td>Item 27</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="day-list">
        <th>12 - 16</th>
        <td>Item 4</td>
        <td>Item 10</td>
        <td>Item 16</td>
        <td>Item 22</td>
        <td>Item 28</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="day-list">
        <th>16 - 20</th>
        <td>Item 5</td>
        <td>Item 11</td>
        <td>Item 17</td>
        <td>Item 23</td>
        <td>Item 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="day-list">
        <th>20 - 24</th>
        <td>Item 6</td>
        <td>Item 13</td>
        <td>Item 18</td>
        <td>Item 24</td>
        <td>Item 30</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: your solution looks great! I would like to use Example2 but there is one more thing. What is the best way to select all items between the min  and the max number of selected items? I mean that currently user is able to select `Item2` and then moves cursor to the right and select `Item9`. The final solution should select all items between `2` and `9` (so `Item3`, `Item4`, ..., `Item8`). Do you have any idea how to do it in the most effective way? I try to add id to every element and then select all required but it not looks smart.

Comment: @karlperson this was not discussed in your original post. Be aware that the user can use *Ctrl* key to select a second item or second group. Take a look at `stop` or `selected` callbacks: http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/

Answer (score 1):

To perhaps improve the layout of what you had in mind and tidy up the code, what you could do is create a form to allow your user to input their list item and allow them to select a date for that list item through a date picker. Materialize have a great one that's powered by jQuery: https://materializecss.com/pickers.html.